# how do I reset Windows 10 to "factory settings"

Tags: windows-10

I have a workstation provided by my (about to become former) employer. Windows 10 was purchased and installed by myself on this machine. I know I can remove the Windows license with the `slmgr` command but is it possible to reset the OS install to "factory" somehow at the same time? As in, a blank Windows 10 install with no users and no app data just waiting for someone to log in and activate it?

My plan right now is to boot into Ubuntu and just wipe the partition, but I would rather leave the machine installed and all setup.

Thanks!

Comment: Per the duplicates: Settings → Update & Security → Recovery → Reset this PC

Comment: Sweet, thanks - I never noticed that option before. Should I remove the license key with slmgr before running this step? Looking at the other answers now to see if that's covered.

Comment: Probably not needed, but not entirely sure for enterprise copies of Windows. I'd leave it.

Comment: This is Win10 Pro, I'll find out when I try the reset. Thanks!

Comment: You should change the license key then perform the Reset

Comment: Bear in mind that if the machine came with Windows preloaded by the manufacturer then it may simply reactivate itself as it has a digital entitlement. It may simply be something you don't need to care about.

Comment: @Mokubai - Which is the reason I suggested changing the license key.  If the machine came with Windows 10 Professional (unclear since this workstation was connected to a corporate network) that would be unnecessary

Comment: @Mokubai it did not come into my possession with a previous version of Windows installed although it may have shipped with one years ago. However, if it does reset itself with that OEM license I am ok as long as my "personal" license is removed/deactivated. Also it is not connected to a traditional corporate network per se, I work from home and can do with it as I please. To clarify: when I received the machine I wiped all data from the disk, purchased a Win Pro license and installed the OS from scratch.