# How do I find the product key for a Windows purchase if I don't have the original email

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have 2 Windows 10 licenses in my Microsoft account that are "floating". One was used on a box I built for my father-in-law which got literally destroyed, and the second one was liberated from a workstation last year (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1651933/how-do-i-reset-windows-10-to-factory-settings)). I can find the purchase dates and order numbers easily in my Microsoft account, but I can find no way to get a product key for either license to re-use it.

How do I go about getting a product key in this case? The emails are long, long gone. Microsoft's 877 help line is remarkably useless in this context.

Comment: You need to remove the machines no longer using Windows (destroyed or whatever) and then add machines in their place. Log into your Microsoft Account to do this.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=find+product+key

Comment: @John The machines are not listed in my Microsoft account. They were both removed months ago. Don't I need to install and activate a new workstation to add it to the machine list?

Comment: You can try that and see if it works.  If not, a hill to climb if no proof of purchase.

Comment: I was hoping the existence of the orders/invoices in my Microsoft account would be proof of purchase, but I am beginning to agree... I guess I will try to reach out to Microsoft again.